# When generating pptx powerpoint presentations in Quarto, how to set font & font background in powerpoint

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc, quarto

I'm using Quarto with R to generate a powerpoint presentation and would like to change the font or at least the font color for code blocks and inline code. Where can I change this?
Can I set this in the `template.pptx`
Ideally, I would like to also set a background for the font associated with code so it stands out a little more.

````
---
title: "My sample presentation"
format: 
  pptx:
    reference-doc: template.pptx
---

# Running Code

When you click the **Render** button a document will be generated that includes both content and the output of embedded code. You can embed code like this:

```{r}
1 + 1
```
````

With `template.pptx` generated using the command from the quarto docs:
[`quarto pandoc -o template.pptx --print-default-data-file reference.pptx`](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/powerpoint.html#creating-a-template)

**Current output:**

[image: Current output]

**Desired output:**

[image: Desired output]

or

[image: Desired output]